# ¿Cómo ver si hay exactamente "x" elementos en un arreglo?

Tags: java, array, bucles, pseudocódigo

Tengo que buscar si hay cierta cantidad de elementos en un arreglo, esta cantidad tiene que ser exacta.

Mi formulación para el problema es la siguiente:

HayExactamenteNElementos(int n , int elemento)

//declaro variables locales.

boolean exacta = true;

int contador = 0;

-Itero por todo el arreglo y le agrego la condición de corte que seria que la variable exacta = true.

-Luego si [i] == [elemento que busco]
contador++.

-Si contador es igual a N entonces
exacta true.

//Ahora mi problema es que el código arroja true y no visualiza lo que le resta del código, ya que tranquilamente el contador se puede pasar de N en lo que resta del arreglo. ¿Cómo soluciono esto? Por favor respuestas en pseudo-código.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que no especificaste bien a que te refieres, y que una anotación es java en eso esta el codgio, debes de plantear bien la pregunta que no tiene sentido que lo pediste en pseudocodigo y en ese caso es mucho mas facil.

```
   import java.util.*;
    public class ArrayLenght {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Primero tienes que delimitar cuanta es la cantidad que quiere comparar 
            Scanner tec = new Scanner(System.in);
            //En este caso 5
            int varDefinida = 5;

            System.out.println("Ingrese el total: ");
            int ingresoDatos = tec.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");

            int[] numero = new int[ingresoDatos];
            for(int i = 0; i< numero.length ; i++ ){
                System.out.println("Ingresa datos: ");
                numero[i] = tec.nextInt();



            }
            System.out.println("\n\nDatos de Array");
             for(int i = 0; i<= numero.length-1; i++ ){          
                System.out.println("Array: "+ numero[i] + " ");

            }
             
             System.out.println("\n\nComparar array:\n");
            if(numero.length > varDefinida){
                System.out.println("Es mayor");
            }else if(numero.length< varDefinida){
                System.out.println("Es menor");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Son iguales");
            }

        }

    }
```

Los dos ciclos se pueden hacer solamente en uno, y un array es estatico que no puede cambiar en ningun momento, solo debes de hacer un if para comparar el

Comment: Si no está claro la pregunta sería mejor no responderla.